# Apache Axis2 1.5.1 and NTLM Authentication

Tags: java, iis, apache-axis, ntlm

I've browsed all of the discussions here on StackOverflow regarding NTLM and Java, and I can't seem to find the answer.  I'll try and be much more specific.

Here's some code that returns a client stub that (I hope) is configured for NTLM authentication:

```
ServiceStub getService() {
  try {
    ServiceStub stub = new ServiceStub(
        "http://myserver/some/path/to/webservices.asmx"); // this service is hosted on IIS
    List<String> ntlmPreferences = new ArrayList<String>(1);
    ntlmPreferences.add(HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator.NTLM);
    HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator ntlmAuthenticator = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
    ntlmAuthenticator.setAuthSchemes(ntlmPreferences);
    ntlmAuthenticator.setUsername("me");
    ntlmAuthenticator.setHost("localhost");
    ntlmAuthenticator.setDomain("mydomain");
    Options options = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, ntlmAuthenticator);
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, "false");
    return stub;
  } catch (AxisFault e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
      return null;
}
```

This returns a valid SerivceStub object.  When I try to invoke a call on the stub, I see the following in my log:

```
Jun 9, 2010 12:12:22 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
INFO: NTLM authentication scheme selected
Jun 9, 2010 12:12:22 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector authenticate
SEVERE: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication: org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials
```

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: I think I have the answer.  Don't use Axis.  Axis says it supports NTLM, but it needs credentials.  This is useless in a SSO environment where we want the ambient credentials.  It should be an easy fix for Axis in Java 6 because Java 6 comes with native NTLM, but I guess they don't care.

I'll try CXF - that should work... or at least I hope it does.

Comment: CXF works fine - drop Axis if you need NTLM.

Comment: There is no code in CXF to handle NTLM. It depends on the NTLM support provided by JDK. When making NTLM work with CXF, we had to set httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);. It didn't work without that property set.

Comment: Check this out!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865539/axis2-client-ntlm-authentication/12204806#12204806

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://robaustin.wikidot.com/axis
It works for me. You need to call setupCertsAndCredential() before getService()

```
private void setupCredential() {
  final NTCredentials nt = new NTCredentials("user", "pass", "", "domain");
  final CredentialsProvider myCredentialsProvider = new CredentialsProvider() {
   public Credentials getCredentials(AuthScheme scheme, String host, int port, boolean proxy) throws CredentialsNotAvailableException {
    return nt;
   }
  };
  DefaultHttpParams.getDefaultParams().setParameter("http.authentication.credential-provider", myCredentialsProvider);
 }

ServiceStub getService() {  

  try {   
    ServiceStub stub = new ServiceStub(   
        "http://myserver/some/path/to/webservices.asmx"); // this service is hosted on IIS   

    return stub;    
  } catch (AxisFault e) {    
      e.printStackTrace();    
  }    
      return null;    
}
```

Comment: as mentioned in my post, I want to use ambient NTLM.  Your post is wrong in that I must provide the credentials when I simply want to pass them on.  Axis does not support this so I went with CXF.

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient doesnt support NTLM v2 hence I use JCIFS library to return NTLM v1,2,3 message type as described in this website

http://devsac.blogspot.com/2010/10/supoprt-for-ntlmv2-with-apache.html

I just used the JCIFS_NTLMScheme.java file from the above website to register the auth scheme and it worked !!!!

Sample client:

```
List authSchema = new ArrayList();
AuthPolicy.registerAuthScheme(AuthPolicy.NTLM, org.tempuri.JCIFS_NTLMScheme.class);
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
auth.setUsername("");
auth.setPassword("");
auth.setDomain("");
auth.setHost("");
auth.setPort();
List authPrefs = new ArrayList(1);
authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);
auth.setAuthSchemes(authPrefs);
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
```