# Invoke web service (.net) from axis 1.4 client - NTLM authentication

Tags: java, web-services, axis, ntlm-authentication

I am calling a web service written in .NET located remotely running under IIS Server.

I created a stub to call the web service using apache axis 1.4. The web service uses NTLM authentication. I try to invoke the web service in this way but the error it's always the same : (401)Unauthorized.

How can I do it?

```
    final String authUser = "username";
    final String authPassword = "password";

    Stub client = new Stub();
    client.setUsername(authUser);
    client.setPassword(authPassword);

    client._setProperty(Stub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url);

    Output output= client.getService();
```

When the web service is not in .NET and it doesn't have NTLM Authentication the client in Axis 1.4 works.

Comment: The fact the webservice is written in .NET is not directly relevant - NTLM auth is applied at the IIS level. It could be a static HTML page and you could still use it. The server-side language is entirely transparent to the client. But the NTLM (note not NTML as you put!) is likely to be part of the issue, yes.

Comment: Anyway see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865539/axis2-client-ntlm-authentication

Comment: So what is your suggestion? I I'm able to invoke the service using jax-ws but with axis 1 it does not work. Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
return new PasswordAuthentication(authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
 }
});

Comment: The link I posted has multiple suggestions, most of which seem to be about using a different library because the one you're using doesn't support NTLM. Unfortunately I can't tell you more, I'm not a Java dev, I saw this because it was tagged asp.net, although as I mentioned that's not really all that relevant to the question. There is no .NET code to fix here. I have removed the tag.

Comment: Ok, good. I would avoid different library but probably Axis 1 doesn't support NTML.